# How to hide thumb on flutter Slider Widget?

Tags: flutter

I have to hide the thumb on Slider widget. I set thumb colour to transparent with SliderTheme widget. It does not work.  How to hide thumb?

I set thumb colour to transparent.

```
Center(
  child: SliderTheme(
    child: Slider(
      value: 50,
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      activeColor: Colors.black,
      inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      onChanged: (double value) {},
    ),
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
      trackHeight: 28, 
      thumbColor: Colors.transparent, 
      thumbShape: null),
  ),
)
```

I expect the slider widget without thumb.

Answer (score 13):

Bit of a workaround but you can set the `thumbShape` to have a radius of 0:

```
Center(
  child: SliderTheme(
    child: Slider(
      value: 50,
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      activeColor: Colors.black,
      inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
      onChanged: (double value) {},
    ),
    data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
        trackHeight: 28,
        thumbColor: Colors.transparent,
        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 0.0)),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 10):

Not a workaround. The correct way to do it.

Set the `thumbShape` to `SliderComponentShape.noThumb`

i.e.

```
SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    trackHeight: 28,
    thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noThumb,
```